# Searching for unbounded, non-negative function $f(x)$ with roots $x_{n}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $y = f(x)$ is unbounded and non-negative for all real $x$,
then is it possible that it can have roots $x_n$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow  \infty$.

Comment: Yes(Try drawing a picture).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $ y = |x \sin(x)|$ has infinitely many roots $x_n$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow  \infty$.

[image: see the pic]

Comment: great.... Thanks sir... This example is quite useful..

Answer (score 6):

For an analytic example, you can take $f : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} [0,+\infty) & \to & \mathbb{R} \\ x & \mapsto & x + x \sin(x) \end{array} \right.$.

Then $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$ or $\sin(x)=-1$ (ie. $x=-\pi/2[2\pi]$) and $f(x) \geq x-x=0$.

---

More generally, you can take $f : x \mapsto g(x)(1+\sin(x))$ where $g(x) \geq 0$. Then the graph is a sinusoid bounded above by $2g(x)$. For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer ... one upvote from my side.

Comment: @seirios .... thanks for nice answer.

Comment: @seirios Could you tell me what software have you used for drawing graph?

Comment: @srijan: I used Maxima.